# How to include a resource in micronaut graalvm native image with gradle buildNativeLambda

Tags: gradle, micronaut, graalvm

As described in [this guide](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/mn-application-aws-lambda-graalvm-gradle-java.html) I am using `./gradlew buildNativeLambda` command to generate zip file containing graalvm native image. I am facing a problem described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931286/micronaut-serverless-application-using-dynamodb-and-graal-custom-runtime-throws) thread so wanted to include resource by passing `-H:IncludeResources` to my command like below:

```
./gradlew buildNativeLambda -H:IncludeResources="com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json"
```

Unfortunately, its failing with `Unknown command-line option '-H'`. How can I pass this to gradle task?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the right way to do it is though `build.gradle` file like below:

```
graalvmNative {
    binaries {
        main {
            buildArgs "-H:IncludeResources=\"com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json\""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct! Where did you find documentation about that?

Comment: This does not work - the lambda for main is definitely wrong. The current implementation takes an `Array<String>` and when I assume these to be CLI args, it tells me `error: source file or directory not found` for every arg and doesn't tell me where or what it's looking for